# Dumping data over ethernet with an arduino client / python server

Tags: python, client-server, arduino

I'm using an arduino ethernet to read data form sensors, and then would like to send data to a computer in another building to drive the logic/control in a piece of python software.  I decided to sketch up a simple sketch in python/arduino that just sends text from the arduino to my python program over ethernet:

The arduino client code is mostly taken from the EthernetClient example:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0E, 0x40, 0x9F};
byte ip[] = {192, 168, 0, 172};
byte server[] = {192,168,0,17};
int port = 1700;

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, port)) {
    Serial.println("connected.");
    //print text to the server
    client.println("This is a request from the client.");
  } 
  else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // if there are incoming bytes available 
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while(true);
  }
}
```

And then my python code:

```
import socket

host = ''
port = 1700
address = (host, port)

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((address))
server_socket.listen(5)

print "Listening for client . . ."

conn, address = server_socket.accept()

print "Connected to client at ", address

//pick a large output buffer size because i don't necessarily know how big the incoming packet is
output = conn.recv(2048);
print "Message received from client:"
print output

conn.send("This is a response from the server.")
conn.close()

print "Test message sent and connection closed."
```

The response from the server is what i expect:

```
Listening for client . . .
Connected to client at  ('192.168.0.172', 1025)
Message received from client:
This is a request from the client.
Test message sent and connection closed.
```

But the client receives:

```
connecting...
connected.
This
disconnecting.
```

And seems to stop receiving the text from my server after the stream.  Why is that?

Another question: Why is it that I asked my arduino to connect on port 1700, but python claims that it's receiving a request from port 1025?

thanks!

Comment: I am not sure but can you try putting a wait after conn.send("This is a response from the server.") and conn.close() in the python code and see what happens?

Comment: Also regarding your question about port, the address returned by socket.accept() is the address of the other end of connection. i.e. connection is established between port 1025 of arduino and port 1700 of host computer(where python code is running)

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the port number -- I realized that a bit too late, but it makes sense :)  I tried adding a 'wait', but it didn't seem to do much -- the arduino still didn't receive the entire message.  Since then I've switched to a web.py server rather than writing my own with the ports, and that's worked out pretty well for me so far.